# How big is the Fourier transform of the log of a polynomial over the p-adic numbers

Tags: nt.number-theory, reference-request, fourier-analysis, p-adic-analysis

Let $f(z_1,\dots,z_n)$ be a polynomial with $p$-adic coefficients, and let $g(z):=log\lvert f(z) \rvert$. If $\xi$ is a complex character of $\mathbb{Z}_p^n$ there exists a number $v=v(\xi)$ such that $\xi$ is trivial on $p^v\mathbb{Z}_p^n$, but not on $p^{v-1}\mathbb{Z}_p^n$. The question is:

> Find an upper bound of $\lvert\hat{g}(\xi)\rvert$ in terms of $v(\xi)$.

If $f$ is a polynomial in one variable, then I get

> $\lvert\hat{g}(\xi)\rvert \ll p^{-v(\xi)}$

The solution is quite simple: One solves the problem for f(z)=z, in which case $\hat g(\xi)$ can be explicitly computed. The general case then follows easily, because we can factor f into linear factors times a non-vanishing function. This solution, however, doesn't work in higher dimensions.

My guess is that the same bound holds for higher dimensions, but I still haven't managed to show that. Has this problem already been solved? Do you know of any books or papers that might be helpful? Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: What is $\hat{g}$ and what do you  mean by $\vert \hat{g}(\xi)\vert$?